# Expected snippet value not showing

Tags: menus

I have a code snippet like this one,

```
<div class="container">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <i class="icon_about"></i>
                        <span class="title">Home</span>
                        <span class="description">Any Description Here Manual/Auto</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

And Im getting the list of menu items from this php code

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=header_menu&container=false'); ?>
```

But the resultant of that cod is somehow like this,

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-14">
            <a href="My_Link"> Home </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, what im missing here is the id="container" inside the  tag and after the anchor tag  the  . I dont really know how to put those I have a reference

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu
```

But the thing is I still cant understand as to how to add what the things Im missing from the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to create this kind of markup simply using wp_nav_menu function . Either change your markup or use the [Custom Walker Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function) that will allow you to create anykind of markup.

Comment: thank you for the reply, and I have checked the `Walker Function` and it just let me add's custom `class/id` into `<ul>` and `<li>` if im not wrong here, and it doesnt let me at a tag inside the `anchor tag`.

Comment: You are welcome . That is an example of how to use it . "The easiest way to build a new walker function is to copy the default class (Walker_Nav_Menu)[http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Nav_Menus/Walker_Nav_Menu.html] from \wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php and simply customize what you need."